# GDAL: GetMaximum and GetMinimum returns no values

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I am trying to get the maximum and minimum pixel values of a tif raster file.

I am using the GetMaximum() and GetMinimum() methods but they return nothing, thus the error I get is: 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

The in file is a small tif raster for testing purposes. I do get the same error with other rasters that actually did work just a couple of days ago.

This is what I have been trying:

```
from osgeo import gdal

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
in_file = gdal.Open("L8_field.tif")
band1 = in_file.GetRasterBand(1)
barray = band1.ReadAsArray()

# Getting the interval value and setting the classes
max_value = band1.GetMaximum()
min_value = band1.GetMinimum()

tot_classes = 5
class_1 = class_x + min_value
class_x = (max_value - min_value) / tot_classes
class_2 = (class_x * 2) + min_value
class_3 = (class_x * 3) + min_value
class_4 = (class_x * 4) + min_value
class_5 = max_value
...
```

I'm using this to classify the raster. So there is more code that actually classifies it. This snippet is meant to grab the equal intervals.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly why `RasterBand.GetMaximum()` and `RasterBand.GetMinimum()` return `None`. Perhaps a raster attribute table needs to be computed before GTiff can access that value on the fly?

You can do similar operations on the `numpy.ndarray` variable `barray`.

```
import numpy as np
# ...
max_value = np.amax(barray)
min_value = np.amin(barray)
```

The obvious problem here is if the nodata value is either the min or max, in which case that would be returned to your displeasure. Landsat has nodata=0.

You can solve that by making a masked array and using the masked array's `min` and `max` methods.

```
import numpy as np
# ...
masked_arr = np.ma.MaskedArray(barray, mask=(barray==0))
max_value = masked_arr.max()
min_value = masked_arr.min()
```

Comment: Numpy solved it! Thank you very much. I had to first set all nan values to 0 with " barray[np.isnan(barray)] = 0 ".  And just as you say, I had to mask the 0 values. After that the calculations work and I have now a nicely classified image.  The problem seems to be with Gdal or the Gtiff driver, but I don't know what.

Comment: @Majkiboy If the NoDataValue is `np.nan` it might be a more secure practice to make the mask using `np.isnan` rather than setting the NoData pixels to 0, If the value 0 is already valid within the raster those pixels may be falsely ignored.

Answer (score 4):

In order for gdal's .GetMinimum() & .GetMaximum() to return values, you first have to compute statistics on the band. Otherwise, it shows up as none. At least, that's my experience with Sentinel1 radar imagery and interferograms. 
Some example code.

```
raster = gdal.Open('YourRasterFile.tiff') # open raster file
band = raster.GetRasterBand(1) # get data into varialbe 'band' so we can actually look at it. 

band.GetMetadata()
if band.GetMinimum is None or band.GetMaximum() is None:
    print("\nGDAL thinks this file has no values: ", file)
    print("[ MAX ] =", band.GetMaximum())
    print("[ MIN ] =", band.GetMinimum())

if band.GetMinimum() is None or band.GetMaximum() is None:
    band.ComputeStatistics(0)

band.GetMetadata()
if band.GetMinimum is None or band.GetMaximum() is None:
    print("\nBollucks to this: ", file)
    print("[ MAX ] =", band.GetMaximum())
    print("[ MIN ] =", band.GetMinimum())
else: 
    print("\nHey, it worked.")
    print("[ MAX ] =", band.GetMaximum())
    print("[ MIN ] =", band.GetMinimum())
```